# "Purissimum penem" in Suetonius's Life of Horace

Tags: vocabulary, horatius, suetonius

Suetonius, in his *Vita Horati*, reports that the emperor Augustus jokingly referred to Horace as a *purissimus penis*:

> Praeterea saepe eum inter alios iocos **purissimum penem** et homuncionem lepidissimum appellat, unaque et altera liberalitate locupletavit.

What is this intended to mean? *Purus* can mean "pure, clean", and also "chaste"; but a meaning "most chaste penis", if that's what's intended, must be ironic, since a little later Suetonius reports that Horace was so lustful that he had a room lined with mirrors in which to watch himself disporting with prostitutes. Is that the joke -- an ironic reference to Horace's lasciviousness?

The [Loeb translation](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Suetonius/de_Poetis/Horace*.html) gives "a most immaculate libertine", but I'm not sure (a) what that means at all, and (b) whether it represents Suetonius's meaning.

Comment: Interesting! The linked translation has a footnote citing some other source. Can you (or someone else) find what is said there?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I found it on p. 166 of this German book (warning, large PDF): https://ia902606.us.archive.org/13/items/kritikundhermene00birtuoft/kritikundhermene00birtuoft.pdf. It seems to be supporting the "lascivious" reading but I don't find it terribly helpful (though I may be missing some nuances of the German).

Comment: Can't *purus* also mean "unmixed" or "unadulterated"? In which case maybe it's "he's a total penis" or "he's all penis [and nothing else]"?

Comment: @JoelDerfner Oh, I like that interpretation! It hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Horace, the man who is the purest penis. The word *penis* when applied to a person indicated someone given to wanton impulses, especially of a sexual nature. For example, from the Satire of Persius:

**Viso si palles, inprobe, nummo, si facis in penem quidquid tibi venit...** (You reprobate, if you faint at the sight of a coin, and come to do whatever your prick suggests...)

Suetonius wrote a biography of Horace in which he noted the poet as being lascivious and given to erotica. So, the court epithet undoubtedly refers to him having a effete and haughty facade, but a prurient inclination.

Comment: What exactly does "in" mean in "in penem"? To fit the translation it would have to be something like "from": "...if you do whatever comes to you from/ through your penis? These aren't usually listed meanings for "in" + accusative.