# In: Ablative or accusative

Tags: grammar-choice

In chapter 4 LLPSI it says "*sacculum suum in mensa ponit*". *Ponit* means put or sets, so indicates a movement. As far as I know *in* in Latin in the meaning of into or onto (as is the case here) takes the accusative, so in *mensam* (Like it would be the case in German). However, the book uses ablative, indicating no movement. Very confusing.

Answer (score 10):

You are entirely correct that *in* with the accusative tends to indicate motion, while *in* with the ablative tends to indicate position.

But placing (*pōnō*) isn't considered a verb of motion: the Latin verb is more like "causes its location to be", and thus there's no real motion involved. (Its English derivative is "to position", from *pōsitiō*, from *pōsitus*.) *Pōnō* is all about the end result. And the end result is that the bag is resting on the table.

> *Sacculum suum in mēnsā pōnit.*
>   He causes his bag to be resting on the table.
>   (Or:) He sets his bag on the table.

If you want to indicate motion, you could use a verb like *ferō* "carry" or *jaciō* "throw":

> *Sacculum suum in villam fert.*
>   He carries his bag into the villa.
>   *Sacculum suum in piscīnam jacit.*
>   He throws his bag into the fishpond.

Comment: Congratulations on your re-election to Moderator. In this answer, https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/19029/1982, Tyler Durden translated, "...si facis in penem quidquid tibi venit..." to, "...and come to do whatever your prick suggests...". What does, "in" + accusative, really mean here? To fit the translation it would have to be "from" or "through"--not among the listed meanings for "in". Any thoughts? (I did ask TD but he didn't reply.)

Answer (score 5):

The preposition *in* is one of a number of prepositions in Latin that can take both the accusative case *and* the ablative case. In the accusative, it can mean *into, against, etc.* and in the ablative, it can mean either *in, at, on,* or *upon*.

The verb *pōnō* is not a verb of motion; it indicates that something (*sacculum suum*) comes to be placed, usually on something (*in mēnsā*).

In the case of your sentence, *mēnsa* is in the ablative (*mēnsā*) to indicate that the subject of the sentence is placing something *on* or *upon* the table:

> *Sacculum suum in mēnsā pōnit.*
>
> *He places his own sack on/upon the table.*